# Get dummies when some categories are not present in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-processing

Say I have a pandas column as below

**Type**
type1

type2

 type3

and now i will take dummies for above as follows: 
`type_dummies = pd.get_dummies(["Type"], prefix="type")`

Then after joing it with the main DataFrame the resulting df would be something like below:

```
df.drop(['Type'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.join(type_dummies)
df.head()

type_type1    type_type2    type_type3
   1              0             0
   0              1             0
   0              0             1
```

But what if in my training set there is an another category as `type4` in `Type` column. So how would I use `get_dummies()` method to generate dummies as much as I want. That is, in this case I want to generate 4 dummy variables although there are only 3 categories in the desired column?

Comment: hmm yep saw that earlier. But the answers was not clear to me as one below given by @Wen. So I asked it anyway and found a good simple answer. thanks for noting anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can using `categroy` data type

```
df.Type=df.Type.astype('category', categories=['type1','type2','type3','type4'])
df
Out[200]: 
    Type
0  type1
1  type2
2  type3
pd.get_dummies(df["Type"], prefix="type")
Out[201]: 
   type_type1  type_type2  type_type3  type_type4
0           1           0           0           0
1           0           1           0           0
2           0           0           1           0
```

Comment: Wow. That did the trick.  Thanks..

Comment: @AshanPriyadarshana Yw~ happy coding